# Hybris widget connection through socket id

Tags: widget, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to create a widget that can communicate with another one through sockets. I've followed the documentation from [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8be2448886691014bf61e8730c819771.html) but I couldn't understand how their example works. I've created the `definition.xml` where I've defined the inputs/outputs, `mychat.zul` and the `controller`. But I couldn't find anywhere in the platform the tag `<widget-connection>` to see that the widget is actually connecting the inputs/outputs to something.. or isn't this the purpose of the tag above?

I've added the widgets via backoffice F4 functionality but their example works only if I add **two** widgets and **SET** the connection between them (because I tried to debug the program and see when it enters in `@SocketEvent` method and it enters only when I have 2 widgets and set the `outcomingMsg` and `incomingMsg`, but isn't enough to only set the `<widget-connection>` with the same sourceWidgetId and targetWidgetId ?).

Maybe I don't understand completely how this works.. If someone can help me I would appreciate :) Thanks.

**P.S.:** I followed the steps from the tutorial above, I am sure that I've created them in the right directory, otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Here is the `<widget-connection>` from `trainingbackoffice-backoffice-widgets.xml`

```
<widget-connection sourceWidgetId="com.training.backoffice.widgets.mychat" outputId="outgoingMsg" targetWidgetId="com.training.backoffice.widgets.mychat" inputId="incomingMsg"/>
```

**EDIT** : Isn't there a way to have only one chat window to communicate with itself ?

Comment: you can accept your own answer as a solution.

Comment: I can accept it only in 2 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The `<widget-connection>` works as I expected BUT -> my widget wasn't instantiated, so I've solved the problem by instantiating it in `trainingbackoffice-backoffice-widgets.xml` like this:

`<widget id="myChat" widgetDefinitionId="com.training.backoffice.widgets.mychat" />` and the widget connection like this:

`<widget-connection sourceWidgetId="myChat" outputId="outgoingMsg" targetWidgetId="myChat" inputId="incomingMsg"/>`