# Add edit an delete/cancel option in hybris backoffice search result

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I want to add edit and cancel option in search result as shown in image. how to add this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

like I've said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872459/product-information-not-coming-in-adaptive-search-hybris-1808) the backoffice extension is build with widgets. To create functionalities you need, please read about [backoffice widgets](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1808/en-US/633a1253bf3844eea4ac13f681c198da.html) and try to create some basic widgets and connect them through sockets. (If you have any problems with widget connections [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854207/hybris-widget-connection-through-socket-id) is a useful question about the example in the documentation). You can take a look [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1808/en-US/8b96d1a8866910149decb0eee2526cf1.html) too, the link will redirect you to a documentation page about "Actions" which are basically widgets too but they're a little bit different.